# Sockets in python client not closing after event read write events in multi-connection server

Tags: python, sockets, events, server, client

I am using this article from real python that allows for multiconnections. However, after I use it with a small change -

1. after sending and receiving messages from the client and server, the client does not close; or
2. all `data.messages` have been exausted, the client does not close.

The goal is to `close the client` after all communication is done from the server and client.

I have tried sock.settimeout(5.0) like methods but they do not work.

Looks like this break does not work which could be the real problem other than settimeout:
`if not sel.get_map(): break`

Second, looks like it does not get into this code while I was checking:

```
if not recv_data:
    print("closing connection", data.connid)
    sel.unregister(sock)
    sock.close()
```

https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/python-sockets-tutorial/multiconn-client.py

The changes to the above code are as follows:

`server.py`

```
import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
messages = [b"Message 1 from server.", b"Message 2 from server."]

def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    print("accepted connection from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            addr=addr,
            inb=b"",
            messages=list(messages),
            outb=b"",
        )
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            data.inb += recv_data
            print("received", recv_data, "from", data.addr)
        else:
            print("closing connection to", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
                print("echoing", repr(data.outb), "to", data.addr)
                sent = sock.send(data.outb)
                data.outb = data.outb[sent:]


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print("listening on", (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=None)
        for key, mask in events:
            if key.data is None:
                accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
            else:
                service_connection(key, mask)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
except:
    print("uncaught error, exiting")
finally:
    sel.close()
```

`client.py`

```
import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
messages = [b"Message 1 from client.", b"Message 2 from client."]


def start_connections(host, port, num_conns):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print("starting connection", connid, "to", server_addr)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            connid=connid,
            recv_total=0,
            messages=list(messages),
            outb=b"",
            inb=b"",
        )
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        print("received", repr(recv_data), "from connection", data.connid)
        if recv_data:
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
            data.inb += recv_data
        if not recv_data:
            print("closing connection", data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb and data.inb:
            print("sending", repr(data.outb), "to connection", data.connid)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port> <num_connections>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port, num_conns = sys.argv[1:4]
start_connections(host, int(port), int(num_conns))

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=1)
        if events:
            for key, mask in events:
                service_connection(key, mask)
        else:
            break
        # Check for a socket being monitored to continue.
        if not sel.get_map():
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
except:
    print("uncaught error, exiting")
finally:
    sel.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL CODE (Echo server and client) OF THE MASTER REPO TUTS:

`gitserver.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()


def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    print("accepted connection from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b"", outb=b"")
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print("closing connection to", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print("echoing", repr(data.outb), "to", data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print("listening on", (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=None)
        for key, mask in events:
            if key.data is None:
                accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
            else:
                service_connection(key, mask)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
finally:
    sel.close()
```

`gitclient.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
messages = [b"Message 1 from client.", b"Message 2 from client."]


def start_connections(host, port, num_conns):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print("starting connection", connid, "to", server_addr)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            connid=connid,
            msg_total=sum(len(m) for m in messages),
            recv_total=0,
            messages=list(messages),
            outb=b"",
        )
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            print("received", repr(recv_data), "from connection", data.connid)
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
        if not recv_data or data.recv_total == data.msg_total:
            print("closing connection", data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
            print("sending", repr(data.outb), "to connection", data.connid)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port> <num_connections>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port, num_conns = sys.argv[1:4]
start_connections(host, int(port), int(num_conns))

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=1)
        if events:
            for key, mask in events:
                service_connection(key, mask)
        # Check for a socket being monitored to continue.
        if not sel.get_map():
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
finally:
    sel.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using a custom created signal and adding handle code for it. Please find it below:

`SERVER.PY`

```
import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
messages = [b"Server", b"process"]

def accept_wrapper(sock, host, port):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    print("accepted connection from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            addr=addr,
            recv_total=0,
            sent_total=0,
            messages=list(messages),
            inb=b"",
            outb=b"",
        )
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    ex = False
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        print("received", repr(recv_data), "from connection", data.addr)
        if recv_data:
            data.inb += recv_data
            
        if not recv_data and not data.messages:
            print("closing connection", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        if (recv_data.decode() == "exit" or "exit" in recv_data.decode()):
            ex = True
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.messages and ex:
            print("closing connection", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
            print("echoing", data.outb, "to", data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print("listening on", (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=None)
        for key, mask in events:
            if key.data is None:
                accept_wrapper(key.fileobj, host, port)
            else:
                service_connection(key, mask)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
except Exception as e:
    print("uncaught error, exiting", e)
finally:
    sel.close()
```

`CLIENT.PY`

```
import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
messages = [b"Client", b"exit"]

def start_connections(host, port, num_conns):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print("starting connection", connid, "to", server_addr)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            connid=connid,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            addr=port,
            recv_total=0,
            sent_total=0,
            messages=list(messages),
            inb=b"",
            outb=b"",
        )
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    ex = False
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        print("received", repr(recv_data), "from connection", data.connid)
        if recv_data:
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
            data.inb += recv_data
            
        if not recv_data and not data.messages:
            print("closing connection", data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        if (recv_data.decode() == "exit" or "exit" in recv_data.decode()):
            ex = True
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.messages and ex:
            print("closing connection", data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb and data.inb:
            print("sending", data.outb, "to connection", data.connid)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]    

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("usage:", sys.argv[0], "<host> <port> <num_connections>")
    sys.exit(1)

host, port, num_conns = sys.argv[1:4]
start_connections(host, int(port), int(num_conns))

try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=1)
        if events:
            for key, mask in events:
                service_connection(key, mask)
        else:
            break
        if not sel.get_map():
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
except Exception as e:
    print("uncaught error, exiting", e)
finally:
    sel.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```